# Standalone VisualGC download link

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I would like to investigate the memory footprint of my web application on Tomcat.  In addition to VisualVM, I would like to use VisulGC as well.

Could someone provide the link for the `standalone VisualGC` download link?  Strangely I could not find it.

Comment: There is a VisualGC plugin for VisualVM.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OP's description "standalone VisualGC" implies he is already aware of the plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must download the [`jvmstat`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jvmstat-142257.html) package, it will contain `visualgc`.